# Scala HashMap: doesn't += reassign to left hand side?

Tags: scala, immutability

I am reading [Seven Languages in Seven Weeks](http://pragprog.com/book/btlang/seven-languages-in-seven-weeks) to get the taste of different programming paradigm. In the chapter about Scala, I found out that collection are immutable (at least the one from `scala.collection.immutable`). 
However, there is an example which confuses me:

```
scala> val hashMap = HashMap(0->0)
scala> hashMap += 1->1
scala> hashMap
res42: scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 1, 0 -> 0)
```

but

```
scala> map = map + 2->2
<console>:9: error: reassignment to val
       map = map + 2->2
```

Is it `+=` reassigning an immutable collection? How is that that `+=` can reassign a `val` `HashMap` while `=` fails?
Moreover, I tried out with other collections (`List` and `Map`) and with "primitive" (`Int`) and `+=` fails with the reassignment error. How are [HashMap](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.HashMap)s special? I do not read anything particular in the Scala API and I cannot find a definition for `+=` operator (I am assuming it to be an operator and not a function even in Scala, as well as in C++ or Java).
Sorry for the dumb question, but since I am new to Scala I am having difficulties finding resources by myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two types of collections in Scala: Mutable and Immutable

1. Mutable: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.package
2. Immutable: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.package

What you used definitely belongs to mutable category and hence can be reassigned. In fact, if you try this:

```
val hashMap = scala.collection.immutable.HashMap(0->0)
hashMap += (1->1)
```

you'll get same error

Comment: Accepted for the links. I knew I was missing some easy point, but I am following the book step by step and the suggestion is: `copy&paste, before trying to code by yourself` and I missed the fact I was importing the `mutable HashMap` (in fact the link I was looking at is for the `immutable version`).

Answer (score 4):

You're right that this works with a `var`, where the compiler can take

```
hashMap += 1->1
```

and desugar it to

```
hashMap = hashMap + 1->1
```

But there's another possibility too.  If your `hashMap` is of the type `scala.collection.mutable.hashMap` then it directly calls the `+=` method defined on that type:

```
hashMap.+=(1->1)
```

No `val` is reassigned, the map just internally mutates itself.

Answer (score 3):

`hashMap` in code sample is `collection.mutable.HashMap[Int,Int]`. Note the `mutable` package.

There is a `mutable` version for many scala collections.

And there is method with name `+=` in `mutable.HashMap`.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike some other languages, `x += y` doesn't always compile into `x = x + y` in Scala. `hashMap += 1->1` is actually an infix method call (`+=` is a valid method name in Scala), which is defined in [mutable.HashMap](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.HashMap) class.

Your first example uses mutable HashMap, as you can see in the last line. [Immutable HashMap](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.HashMap) doesn't have `+=` method.

Comment: Thanks. I was in fact looking for the `+=` function (this is something I already got, that what in Java is an operator in Scala can be either an operator AND a method), but of course I could not find `+=` in the `immutable HashMap` API

Answer (score 1):

Note that for a mutable `HashMap`

```
scala> val map = scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[Int,Int](0 -> 0)
map: scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[Int,Int] = Map(0 -> 0)
```

its contents can be changed without using `val` or `var`,

```
scala> map += 1->1
res1: map.type = Map(1 -> 1, 0 -> 0)
scala> map += 2->2
res2: map.type = Map(2 -> 2, 1 -> 1, 0 -> 0)
scala> map
res3: scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[Int,Int] = Map(2 -> 2, 1 -> 1, 0 -> 0)
```

However for an immutable `HashMap` declared with `val`

```
scala> val imap = scala.collection.immutable.HashMap[Int,Int](0 -> 0)
imap: scala.collection.immutable.HashMap[Int,Int] = Map(0 -> 0)
```

we cannot for instance add new pairs,

```
scala> imap += 1->1
<console>:10: error: value += is not a member of scala.collection.immutable.HashMap[Int,Int]
              imap += 1->1
                   ^
```

However we can create a new `HashMap` from the original and add a new pair,

```
scala> val imap2 = imap.updated(1,1)
imap2: scala.collection.immutable.HashMap[Int,Int] = Map(0 -> 0, 1 -> 1)
```

Even so, an immutable `HashMap` declared with `var`

```
scala> var imap = scala.collection.immutable.HashMap[Int,Int](0 -> 0)
imap: scala.collection.immutable.HashMap[Int,Int] = Map(0 -> 0)
```

allows for updating the contents,

```
scala> imap += 1->1
scala> imap
res11: scala.collection.immutable.HashMap[Int,Int] = Map(0 -> 0, 1 -> 1)
```